# Updating to 3.7.19 query

Tags: updates

The update notes say:

> After updating, run the following command for each Structure section, to prune unneeded >structure data for drafts and revisions.
>
> php craft utils/repair/section-structure

I don't have the ability to run this CL instruction on the server.

Is it vital that I run it?

What will happen if I don't?

Could I delete this unneeded data from the database directly in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the query is not required – you can tell that by the version number. Craft doesn't use strict semantic versioning, but backwards incompatible changes are reserved for minor updates (a change in the second version number, like 3.**8**.0).

This comment by Brandon Kelly indicates that the repair command only prunes superfluous data:

> Remember, after updating you should run the following command for each of your Structure sections, to prune out any structure data that doesn’t need to be there anymore:
> `php craft utils/resave/section-structure <sectionHandle>`

So the only thing you're missing by not running the command is an opportunity to reduce the database in size.